# How to find the particular names in sql tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to check the name is present in five tables or not,if the name is presented in five table means that person is qualified else rejected,how to do that., any ideas,any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Cnt int = 0;
DECLARE @t TABLE ( TableName VARCHAR(20));

SELECT TableName
INTO @t
FROM ( SELECT 'Table1' TableName
       FROM Table1
       WHERE Name = @Name

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 'Table2'
       FROM Table2
       WHERE Name = @Name

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 'Table3'
       FROM Table3
       WHERE Name = @Name

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 'Table4'
       FROM Table4
       WHERE Name = @Name

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 'Table5'
       FROM Table5
       WHERE Name = @Name
       ) a

SELECT a.TableName
FROM ( SELECT 'Table1'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Table2'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Table3'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Table4'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Table5') a
LEFT JOIN @t b
ON a.TableName = b.TableName
WHERE b.TableName IS NULL

SELECT @Cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM @t
```

Comment: @Nithin-i also check that in which table he is not presented,before i tried by UNION function,its retriving from all tables.,

Comment: I have updated the query. The second SELECT statement will return all the tables in which the use is not present.

Comment: You mind explaining why/how your code only answer solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Which part you have not understood?
Replace all Table1, Table2, etc. with actual table names.

Comment: I'm with @DrCopyPaste on this one. What have you written? You might want to go and re-read the question as I think you've over-thought it to the point of confusion.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan tbh I just skimmed through your code, because you added no explanation. IMHO, it really doesnt matter what `I` didn't understand. For starters the question seems a bit generic, i.e. no sample data/sample code/input values/desired output was given, but yet you provide an answer with no explanation as to how to use it and that is what's bothering me. In other words: the limits to answering the question are pretty broad because of the question's broadness (is that a word?), so in order to give a proper solution one should first define those limits in which the answer will work.

Comment: "DrCopyPaste-my question is very simple,i want to fetch the data from five tables by name(may be same person(id) or different person(id)).the thing is what i am feeling complex is,in which are the tables the person is not presented.i want to show the tables names which they not presented.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan-the thing i dont know how to use the code,its showing error"Must declare the table variable "@t".,

Comment: I hope you have a copied the entire the code that I have shared, because I have declared the table varibale. Replace all Table1, Table2, etc. with your actual table names. And also replace @Name variable name with your variable name.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan-Thanks for the help,now its working fine for me,the thing is i need to find the table name,just now i came know that want to find the table names,i want to display the table names which the name is not prsent.For ex.there five tables-Ta1,Ta2,Ta3,Ta4,Ta5.In these tables Sarvan is presented in five table is not,if its presented in Ta1 Ta2 Ta3,i want to display the non prsent table like Ta4 and Ta5....

Comment: @Sarvan: Firstly please accept the answer. Secondly the second SELECT statement will give you all the table names in which the employee is not present. You just have to replace the dummy name that is Table1, Table2 etc. with you actually table name say Ta1, Ta2, or whatever it is. You need to do this in both SELECT and FROM clause.